# How to run php7 nginx on amazon ec2 ? (elastic IP?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've installed nginx and php7 to amazon EC2.
It works when I check it via local IP. But it's not available via Elastic IP.
Could somebody help me with it?

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html;

server_name 52.43.19.61;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your questions. I'm not a pro to check this all. I use all the standard settings ec2. Just installed nginx and php7

Answer (score 0):

Couple questions:

- Your elastic IP associated with your instance?
- Your security group of instance permits incoming connections?
- Your instance firewall permits incoming connections?
- Your application listens
- what port are you trying to access?
- Do you have that port open on the security groups? Do you have an
  application listening on that port?
- Also make sure Route table of VPC is set to enable IP address outside
  the VPC (0.0.0.0/0) to flow from the subnet to the Internet gateway.
- If I had to guess your security groups are not setup right. Make sure
  to open them to the correct ip addresses or to the world (0.0.0.0/0)
  if you are going access that port from multiple IPs.

If all that is not it, then dissociate and reallocate the IP to the instance.